# Анимация линий при наведении на кнопку

Tags: html, css, css-animation

[image: схема]

1. Как нарисовать такую линию?
2. Как сделать чтобы она появлялась слева на право при наведении на кнопку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Animation и @keyframes

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH9hp.png');
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 100px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffa60e;
}

.button:hover .line {
  animation: .8s linear forwards draw_line;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 130%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.start {
  bottom: calc(0% - 4px);
  left: calc(0% - 3px);
}

.angle {
  bottom: calc(0% - 4px);
  left: calc(100% - 3px);
}

.final {
  bottom: calc(100% - 4px);
  left: calc(100% - 3px);
}

@keyframes draw_line {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  1% {
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  65% {
    width: 240px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 240px;
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="line"><b class="dot start"></b><b class="dot angle"></b><b class="dot final"></b></div>
</div>
```

## Transition: delay и duration

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH9hp.png');
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto -40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffa60e;
}

.line_right {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 130%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition-property: opacity, width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.0s, 0.0s;
  transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  /* раскомментировать для "вправо-и-вниз" */
  /* transform: scale(1, -1); */
}
.button:hover .line_right {
  width: 240px;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition-property: opacity, width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.1s, 0.6s, 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.1s, 0.7s;
}

.line_bottom {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 130%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition-property: opacity, width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.0s, 0.0s;
  transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  /* transform: rotate(90deg); "вниз-и-вправо" */
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);/* "вниз-и-влево" */
}
.button:hover .line_bottom {
  width: 60px;
  height: 240px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition-property: opacity, width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.1s, 0.2s, 0.6s;
  transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.1s, 0.3s;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}
.start {
  bottom: calc(0% - 4px);
  left: calc(0% - 3px);
}
.angle {
  bottom: calc(0% - 4px);
  left: calc(100% - 3px);
}
.final {
  bottom: calc(100% - 4px);
  left: calc(100% - 3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="line_right"><b class="dot start"></b><b class="dot angle"></b><b class="dot final"></b></div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="line_bottom"><b class="dot start"></b><b class="dot angle"></b><b class="dot final"></b></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можешь подсказать, что бы ещё и плавно исчезала линия, где и что прописать?

Comment: И почему у меня не получается привязать этот код к input?

Comment: к input привязать удалось, а вот как добавить в js плавное исчезание не знаю. Можете на коде , который вы написали выше сделать плавное исчезание?

Comment: Спасибо друг, учусь)

Comment: Друг подскажи как сделать , чтобы линия шла вниз, хотя тебе уже место в раю обеспечено)

Comment: можешь досказать как сделать линию, чтобы шла вниз и влево. Уже перепробовал всё, что знал.

Comment: @ВадимЯнущик дополнил.